# why is the bg colour of the saved turtle fig. not black(as per the colour stated) ? and how to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from PIL import Image, EpsImagePlugin
import os
import turtle

EpsImagePlugin.gs_windows_binary=r'C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs10.01.2\bin\\gswin64c'

point=turtle.Turtle(); point.speed(0); point.color('yellow')
point.penup(); point.sety(- 6*25); point.pendown()

point.begin_fill()
point.circle(6*25, steps=6)
point.end_fill()

point.hideturtle()

screen=turtle.Screen(); screen.bgcolor('black')[turtle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t5V0.png)
board=screen.getcanvas(); board.postscript(file="test_drawing.eps")

Image.open("test_drawing.eps").save("test_drawing.jpg", "JPEG")
Image.open(r'C:\\Users\\parth\Desktop\\coding\\test_drawing.jpg').show()[saved image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asQUQ.png)
Image.open(r'C:\\Users\\parth\Desktop\\coding\\test_drawing.jpg').rotate(45, fillcolor='black', expand=True).show()[the output i want but with a complete black bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYpF6.png)

os.remove(path=r'C:\\Users\\parth\Desktop\\coding\\test_drawing.jpg')
```

how can i fix this code so that the saved fig has a black bg instead of the default black one ?

hope someone can help me fix this block of code.